# Integrating Zenoss mails (data Logs) with MySQL database table?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, logging

I have installed Zenoss monitoring tool on my PC and I want to store every outgoing email from the Zenoss to a database. Does any one know how I can achieve this. I just use this server to send emails and I use Google Apps to receive emails. And i want to store all this mail to my MySQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually zenoss uses the MySql for storing all the details and when we configure it, It will read the details from these tables and sends it to the mail server. so if we want to store these mail data to MySql, We can read and store it by reading all the fields from these table and store it in you'r MySql table.